# Rails token authentication with API. Where does the token go?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, token, api-design

First of all, I am fairly new to Rails and this is the first time I'm trying to use a token based authentication process!

So, in my sessions_controller (client app) I have this snippet to fetch the user token from my Rails API:

```
#basic auth
uri_tk = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000/token")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri_tk.host, uri_tk.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri_tk.request_uri)
request.basic_auth(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
response = http.request(request)
```

And on my application_controller (api app) I have this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API

 include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
 include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token::ControllerMethods

 before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token, except: [:token]

 include Authenticable

 respond_to :json

 def token
  authenticate_with_http_basic do |email, password|
    user = User.find_by(email: email)
    if user &&  user.match_password(password)
      render json: {token: user.auth_token}
    else
      render json: {error: 'Incorrect credentials' }, status: 401
    end
  end
 end

 private

  def authenticate_user_from_token
    unless authenticate_with_http_token { |token, options| User.find_by(auth_token: token)}
       render json: {erro: 'Bad Token'}, status: 401
    end
  end

end
```

So, my problem is: when we reach the point where all subsequent requests need to pass through "authenticate_user_from_token", there is no token to authenticate from. Should I store the token in the client session? Do I have to specify the token in every request I make?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The before filter expects `user.auth_token` to be passed in subsequent requests. You are sending it as json response from `token` method. It looks like you just need to pass it in the other requests. (Secondly this looks very insecure. If I get the auth token value then I can impersonate that user)

Comment: And how would I pass the `user.auth_token` in subsequent requests? (I knew I had to this but, honestly, I just don't know how)
What should I do to better secure the app? 
Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: You may set the auth_token as a data attr or as a global variable. (bad way as I said before). On subsequent request append the token to the data that you send to your server.

Comment: Should I append the token in every request I send? Isn't there a more approachable way to do this?